# Limit CSS and JS to Rails Engine

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have created a Rails Engine and its CSS and Javascript are changing the host application layout.

Is there a way of confining the assets to the Engine Views without changing the entire application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes as namespaces to scope your css and javascript.

For example if you setup your layout as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    # ...
  </head>
  <% content_tag :body, class: [controller_name, action_name] 
 do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</html>
```

This will let you create CSS rules that apply to only one controller and or action:

```
body.users h1 {
  color: "blue"
} 

body.users.show h1 {
  color: "black"
}
```

And you can scope javascript as well by using delegation.

```
$('body.users').on('click', 'h1', function(){
  alert("This works on any action for the users controller");
});

$('body.users.show').on('click', 'h1', function(){
  alert("This should only work on the show view");
});
```

You can apply this same principle to an engine by creating a helper which outputs a body tag (or any tag really) with "scoping" classes:

```
# /lib/my_engine/helpers/tags_helper.rb
module MyEngine
  module TagsHelper
    def body_tag(**options, &block)
      options[:class] ||= []
      options[:class] << "my_engine" if controller.try(:my_engine_controller?)
      content_tag(:body, options) { yield }
    end
  end
end

# /lib/my_engine/engine.rb
require 'helpers/tag_helper'

module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    ActionView::Base.send :include, MyEngine::TagsHelper
  end
end
```

This assumes that the controllers in your engine respond to `my_engine_controller?`(like Devise does with the `devise_controller?`.

Then it just needs to implemented in the layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    # ...
  </head>
  <%= body_tag do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</html>
```

And you need to scope your css/js to `.my_engine`.